# Listing files with spaces in name

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, zsh

**Problem**

In some directory, I have some files with spaces (or maybe some special character) in their filenames.

Trying to list one file per line, I used `ls -1` but files with spaces in name are not processed as I expected.

**Example**

I have these three files:

```
$ ls -1 
My file 1.zip
My file 2.zip
My file 3.zip
```

and I want to list and do something with them, so I use a loop like this:

```
for i in `ls -1 My*.zip`; do
    # statements
    echo $i;
    # Do something with each file;
done
```

But like split names with spaces:

```
My
file
1.zip
My
file
2.zip
My
file
3.zip
```

**Question**

How can I solve this?, Is there some alternative in shell?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use output from `ls`, use:

```
for f in *.zip; do
    echo "processing $f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

By not using `ls`, and by quoting properly.

```
for i in My*.zip
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s dotglob
for i in *;
do :; # work on "$i"
done
shopt -u dotglob
```

*By default, files that begin with a dot are special in that `*` will not match them.*